# how can I parse a table in javascript when table is formatted with title text

Tags: javascript, parsing, dom

I need to scrape a web page to retreive text from an html table loaded into a $data string (which i have accomplished), to add to a mysql query for insertion into a db, however I am a N00b at parsing, as each  row has a 'table' value I would like to pass a function the value of the table to retreive the value. I am using Wikipedia as a test as it formats the table in the same way.

```
<table class="infobox plainlist" style="width:22em"><caption>Canis Major</caption><tbody>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size: 110%;">Constellation</td>
</tr>
<tr><th scope="row"><a href="/wiki/Right_ascension" title="Right ascension">Right ascension</a></th>
<td>&#160;06<sup>h</sup>&#160;12.5<sup>m</sup> to &#160;07<sup>h</sup>&#160;27.5<sup>m</sup><sup id="cite_ref-boundary_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-boundary-1">&#91;1&#93;</a></sup></td>
</tr>

<tr><th scope="row"><a href="/wiki/Declination" title="Declination">Declination</a></th>
<td>−11.03° to −33.25°<sup id="cite_ref-boundary_1-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-boundary-1">&#91;1&#93; </a></sup></td>
</tr>

<tr><th scope="row">Quadrant</th>
<td>SQ2</td>
</tr>

<tr><th scope="row"><a href="/wiki/88_modern_constellations_by_area" class="mw-redirect" title="88 modern constellations by area">Area</a></th>
<td>380 sq. deg. (<a href="/wiki/88_modern_constellations_by_area" class="mw-redirect" title="88 modern constellations by area">43rd</a>)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am wanting to create a function that when passed 'Declination' it will return the value in the `<td></td>` tag immediatley after it which would be −11.03° to −33.25°.

Comment: it would really depend on how you're doing it. if you're doing it from the browser - eg after making an ajax call or via the console - then you have the DOM apis you can use. If you're doing it via node you're probably better off using a library that provides similar dom functions.

Comment: use cheerio(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) library to parse & extract data easily like jquery.